# Setting TOC depth not working

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm using a `\documentclass[11pt]{book}` document.

I have tried to define a TOC with a maximum depth of 4 with:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\tableofcontents
```

The resulting pdf document doesn't take into account my setting and goes to the deepest level in my TOC.

I have not see anything relevant in the console, but I'm really a novice in LaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are telling LaTeX to number sectional units introduced by `\chapter` (level 0), `\section` (level 1), `\subsection` (2), `\subsubsection` (3) and `\paragraph` (4), including them in the table of contents, which is produced by `\tableofcontents` and *not* by `\makeindex`. Please, try  adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Well perhaps 4 is your deepest level (4 goes down to `\paragraph`). Try what happens if you use 0. If this doesn't change the toc then you probably reset the value somewhere else in your document.

Comment: @UlrikeFisher You are right, I was misunderstanding TOC levels. A 0 level means my `\chapter` level was included in TOC, so for a depth of 4 like `3.2.1.3` I need to set the depth to 3.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The sectional levels are numbered starting from 0:

> `\chapter` is level 0
>   `\section` is level 1
>   `\subsection` is level 2
>   `\subsubsection` is level 3
>   `\paragraph` is level 4
>   `\subparagraph` is level 5

If you want to number up to four levels, you need to set

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

The independent counter for the inclusion in the table of contents is `tocdepth` and respects the same values.

The complete truth is that there is also a level –1, which corresponds to `\part`. So for *no* numbering whatsoever, use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}` or a lower value.

Comment: With `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` I have only subsections, and with `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` I get paragraphs and subparagraphs (and this is with fully nested subparagraphs, not the skip-a-level mechanism you just showed me) showing in the TOC.  Trying to get subsubsections, without paragraphs.  Do you know if `amsbook` does this differently?

Comment: Found it, amsbook uses `\let\l@paragraph\l@subsubsection`
giving paragraphs the same depth as subsubsections.  It should be `\def\l@paragraph{\@tocline{4}{0pt}{1pc}{9pc}{}}`