# texinfo @summarycontents - how can I adjust the level depth?

Tags: table-of-contents, texinfo

I wrote/edit a texinfo manual, specifically the [GNU Emacs Lisp Bytecode Reference
Manual](http://rocky.github.io/elisp-bytecode.pdf), and if you look on page *i* (sheet 2) there is a short table of contents, but it is *too* short.

So I'd like to include one more level, i.e. the section headings as well as the chapter headings that are already there.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you searched for "toc depth level"? I think that a command like `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` (or `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}` depending on your document class) should do the trick. See [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61061) for more explanations.

Comment: While this may be fine for LaTeX there is no sucn thing for texinfo that I know of. I just looked at the texinfo.tex file and I guess I'll answer my own question. Thanks though for looking at this and sharing what you know.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the *texinfo.tex* file and it appears that a short table of contents just redefines the macros for sections and subsections to null.

Here then is a diff:

```
diff -u texinfo-hacked.tex{~,}
--- texinfo-hacked.tex~ 2019-10-07 16:44:56.000000000 -0400
+++ texinfo-hacked.tex  2019-11-29 12:41:46.105737894 -0500

@@ -6881,15 +6881,18 @@
     \rm
     \hyphenpenalty = 10000
     \advance\baselineskip by 1pt % Open it up a little.
-    \def\numsecentry##1##2##3##4{}
-    \let\appsecentry = \numsecentry
-    \let\unnsecentry = \numsecentry
-    \let\numsubsecentry = \numsecentry
-    \let\appsubsecentry = \numsecentry
-    \let\unnsubsecentry = \numsecentry
-    \let\numsubsubsecentry = \numsecentry
-    \let\appsubsubsecentry = \numsecentry
-    \let\unnsubsubsecentry = \numsecentry
+    % Wwe want section
+    % headers in our short contents
+    \def\nullentry##1##2##3##4{}
+    % \def\numsecentry##1##2##3##4{}
+    % \let\appsecentry = \numsecentry
+    % \let\unnsecentry = \numsecentry
+    \let\numsubsecentry = \nullentry
+    \let\appsubsecentry = \nullentry
+    \let\unnsubsecentry = \nullentry
+    \let\numsubsubsecentry = \nullentry
+    \let\appsubsubsecentry = \nullentry
+    \let\unnsubsubsecentry = \nullentry
     \openin 1 \tocreadfilename\space
     \ifeof 1 \else
       \readtocfile
```