# Table of contains as only Chapter and will show lof, lot

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I want to keep ToC to show only chapters but the list of tables and list of the figure will be visible. how can I code for it? I am using `report` as `documentclass`.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! Can you share your code as a minimal working example(MWE) ? Also, can you be more specific as to what you want? It is not clear if you want to have a list of figues and tables available in your ToC or not.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61033/setting-toc-depth-not-working

Comment: `\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}` should show only up to `\chapter` (level `0` sectional unit) and `\clearpage \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures} \listoffigures`.